# Pygame quitting to gameOver screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

New to python, making a snake game but Pygame keeps quitting to the screen but i basically want to be able to quit the game with the X(window's x)button anytime i want to. I've tried debugging this but for some reason i always get not responding when debugging it in PyCharm the gameOver screen is only suppose to run when the bool is set to true but it is somehow clashing with my game pause code. Would really appreciate some help!

This is the code:
http://pastebin.com/eFMU3HH9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gameOver screen you run second `gameloop()` so when you quit you return from second `gameloop()` to first `gameloop()` (or from third to second, etc).

Comment: I understand but you know how to fix this?

Comment: in place of `gameloop()` copy lines `gameExit = False` to `resume = False` (lines number from 32 to 45) - http://pastebin.com/Hj7A2r0e

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate it. Your way is much much much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
size = [700, 500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Game Over Example")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Starting position of the rectangle
rect_x = 50
rect_y = 50

# Speed and direction of rectangle
rect_change_x = 5
rect_change_y = 5

# This is a font we use to draw text on the screen (size 36)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)

# Use this boolean variable to trigger if the game is over.
game_over = False

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:

    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        # We will use a mouse-click to signify when the game is
        # over. Replace this, and set game_over to true in your
        # own game when you know the game is over. (Like lives==0)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            game_over = True

    # --- Game Logic

    # Only move and process game logic if the game isn't over.
    if not game_over:
        # Move the rectangle starting point
        rect_x += rect_change_x
        rect_y += rect_change_y

        # Bounce the ball if needed
        if rect_y > 450 or rect_y < 0:
            rect_change_y = rect_change_y * -1
        if rect_x > 650 or rect_x < 0:
            rect_change_x = rect_change_x * -1

    # --- Draw the frame

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw the rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [rect_x, rect_y, 50, 50])

    if game_over:
        # If game over is true, draw game over
        text = font.render("Game Over", True, WHITE)
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_x = screen.get_width() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        text_y = screen.get_height() / 2 - text_rect.height / 2
        screen.blit(text, [text_x, text_y])

    else:
        # If game isn't over, draw this stuff.
        text = font.render("Click to end game", True, WHITE)
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_x = screen.get_width() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        text_y = screen.get_height() / 2 - text_rect.height / 2
        screen.blit(text, [text_x, text_y])

    # Limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```